# Truncate select text in vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Here's my basic select in vuetify

```
<v-select
   :items="selectablePlaces"
   :label="$t('placeLabel')"
   v-model="placeId"
   required
></v-select>
```

I want to add to every single select In my app this style:

```
width: 100px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

or add any possible vue trait to the element, so the text won't be filling the whole screen. How can I achieve that?

here's example of my code https://codepen.io/zbyszek-kisy/pen/vYNzWRO
I want all option to be shorten to 100px

Comment: What's holding you from adding that style to all vuetify `<v-select>` instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class to `v-select`, [codepen](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/QWjVOqM) simple

Comment: so maybe my css was wrong, as the options are still long like here: https://codepen.io/zbyszek-kisy/pen/vYNzWRO

Comment: @ZbyszekKisły same issue for me, how did you solved?